# How to overwrite font size inside an iframe and keep it after changing url

Tags: html, iframe, font-size

I have a responsive webpage, name it A for better understanding.

I have to use an iframe to load A in another page for specific purpose and present it as a normal content in the page, name that page B.

Because A has set font size change for specific window width, when my boss uses minimized window browser of B, he sees the content of A is small.

He wants the font size of A to be as big as larger screen of A but in the iframe of B with smaller window width. So now I have to make an overwrite only for iframe.

I have tried with javascript catching onload event and do overwrite font size,  but when the user clicks on a link inside the iframe, after changing window location, all the changes are removed.

I have also tried to put an param on the url when loading the iframe in, so based on that I can store to cookies and know that the user are using iframe. But when user accesses the normal link of A, cookies still exists and show the overwrite font size, it needs to be reset but I don't know how.

Please help me with your solutions or just give me your idea of how to do that.

Comment: This sounds like an X/Y problem. If you use Ajax, you can load the URL into the page you are on since I assume it is from the same origin (if not then no chance). Anyway, please visit [help] and see [ask]

Comment: Clear the cookie when not in an iFrame - if top==self

Comment: Hi mplungjan, how can I know that A is used as iframe, and the script clear cookies should write on page A or page B. Thanks

Comment: I just told you. `if (top==self) /* ignore cookies */; else changeFont()` or don't use cookies, just  `if (top!=self) changeFont()`

Comment: It works, thank you so much mplungjan